# Aligning braced array material inside a tabular

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am setting some tables which are largely mathematical but which semantically feel better as `tabular`s. Most are straight-forward but a few have entries which need `cases`-like entries for some parts. My current approximation is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *{3}{>{$}r<{$}} l}
  Entry & A & B  & C & Notes \\
  1     & 1 & -1 & 1 & Stuff \\
  2     & \left\{ \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right.
        & \left. \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right.
        & \left. \begin{array}{r} 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right\}
        & More stuff \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but the alignment is off.

I suspect I need a mixture of `amsmath` features, but I'm not sure of the correct recipe, particularly to retain the semantics of the structure.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you want to use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l *{3}{>{$}r<{$}} l}
  Entry & A & B  & C & Notes \\
  1     & 1 & -1 & 1 & Stuff \\
  2     & \begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}
        & \begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}
        & \begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ 1 \end{array}
        & More stuff \\
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix\{{3-2}{3-4}\}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that one can also `right-xshift` the closing brace: that's handy for my real use case, where I have `\epsilon^{*}` to align and need 'ignore' the star for alignment.